# Secondary mail provider

Tags: email, g-suite, mx-record

At present I am using Google Apps for my domain, but I want to set up another email provider through my domain as a second MX server, in case Gmail fails (it only promises 99.99% uptime).

I tried using Outlook.com for my domain, but it won't accept other MX records while claiming ownership - which will cause downtime.

Is there any way to fix this or use another free online email provider for my domain?

Comment: Do you remember when you added the MX records for Google Apps to your domain records? You added _five_ of them. What do you suppose are the chances that _all five of Google's incoming mail servers will fail at the same time_?

Comment: Also, if none of the SMTP servers in the MX-records is up, the mail will be queued and tried to be resent at a later time. There is extremely low risk that you will ever loose a mail.

Comment: I agree, mailservers keep and try to send the mail 24 hours by default. some even longer. In that case 'only' 99.99% uptime is more then enough

Answer (score 5):

There are some redundancies built into the SMTP protocol, specifically the retry interval. I've seen this run as long as four days, so I would not be concerned about this at all. Google has multiple MX targets, so you will most-likely receive your mail, even in the event of a temporary outage. Its delivery may be delayed, but your mail won't be lost.